# reledpar and pages environment

Tags: reledpar

[reledpar](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledpar.pdf) - section 5  Facing pages 5.1  Basic usage - asks for a `pages environment`, is there any one?
The following does not produce a two facing pages output:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\title{Two languages on facing pages}
\author{mc}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside} Language ONE \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside} Language TWO \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

```
Package reledpar Error: \Pages called without previous `pages` environment. \end
```

I am sure it is something silly, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is not correct. What is missing here is `\beginnumbering…\endnumbering` and `\pstart`…`\pend` structure.

Here a correct version

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\title{Two languages on facing pages}
\author{mc}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
   \beginnumbering
   \pstart
   Language ONE 
   \pend 
   \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
   Language TWO

   \pend
   \endnumbering 
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

I will correct this bad message.

Comment: thanks, it works! (I am trying a few things, look for more queries, I appreciate your help)

Comment: please validate the answer and up it

Comment: I have tested again, end before the "\Pages called without previous `pages` environment" message, there was already `Missing \pstart…\pend inside `Leftside` environment`. So this previous message is the correct one.

Comment: @ Maieul I am not sure to understand the point of your last comment

Comment: With the actual version of reledmac, there was, with your MWE, a message which tell you that you have ommited \pstart…\pend. So there is no lack on the message of reledmac.