# Overlapping text and not working "\newpage" when using reledmac & reledpar packages

Tags: text, page, reledmac, reledpar

## Original Question

I have a booklet written with the package [matrita](https://github.com/franen/matrita). Now, I would like to extend that booklet to two languages, on **facing pages** (left pages in one language and right pages in another language), and I am currently using the `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
 \usepackage{reledmac}
 \usepackage{reledpar}
 \numberlinefalse 
 \usepackage[]{matrita}
```

Also, I am using a structure for facing pages provided by [Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712/ma%C3%AFeul) in the [reledpar and pages environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321023/reledpar-and-pages-environment) thread:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\numberlinefalse 
\title{Two languages on facing pages}
\author{mc}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
   \beginnumbering
   \pstart

   Text for Language ONE 

   \pend 
   \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart

   Text for Language TWO

   \pend
   \endnumbering 
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

However, once I compile my code,

1. `\newpage` looks like not working, as shown in this picture (in this case, the command `\newpage` is right before the heading `Seconda Lettura`)

[image]

2. The linespacing throughout the entire text is quite messed up, i.e. often the linespacing is very small and the text (of two lines) partially overlaps, as shown in the following picture (on the left there is the original layout, i.e. not using the `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages, while on the right, the layout by using the `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages):

[image]

**How can I solve both problems related to (1) `\newpage` and (2) linespacing, resulting in an overlapping text ?**

## Edited Question with MWE

Thanks to the @marquinho's comments (under this question), I created two versions of MWE. The first version does not include any `reledmac` and `reledpar` package, while the second version includes both `reledmac` and `reledpar` packages.

Please bear in mind that you need the following `sty` files to run the MWEs:

1. `matrita.sty` generated from `matrita.dtx`, which is downloadable from the [Matrita package website](https://github.com/franen/matrita).
2. `reledmac.sty`
3. `reledpar.sty`

In addition, just for information, I am using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) as text editor and I compile with `pdfLaTex`.

### MWE without `reledmac` and `reledpar`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
% % reledpar and reledmac packages
% % https://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/reledmac/
% \usepackage{reledmac}
% \usepackage{reledpar}
% \numberlinefalse 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[paperwidth=120mm,paperheight=210mm,top=12mm,bottom=25mm,outer=20mm,inner=13mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{matrita}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\respfont}{\bfseries}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{respcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{etgray}{gray}{0.8}
\setlength{\afterpoemtitleskip}{2ex plus 0ex minus 1ex}
\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus 2ex}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
\setlength{\titleindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\definecolor{crosscolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\renewcommand{\intestfont}[1]{{\Large\scshape\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\nomelibrofont}[1]{{\bfseries#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCoffin\InitialCoffin
\NewCoffin\RestCoffin
\NewCoffin\LineCoffin
\newlength{\InitKernCorr}
\tl_new:N \Part_Title_tl
\tl_new:N \Rest_of_Title_tl
\tl_set:Nn \First_Title_tl {\tl_head:N \Part_Title_tl}
\tl_set:Nn \Rest_of_Title_tl {\tl_tail:N \Part_Title_tl}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\momento}{O{0em}m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \Part_Title_tl {#2}
  \setlength{\InitKernCorr}{#1}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\InitialCoffin{
    \normalfont\scalebox{2}{\Large\textcolor{red}{\First_Title_tl}\hspace{\InitKernCorr}}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\RestCoffin{
    \normalfont\Large\textcolor{red}{\MakeTextUppercase \Rest_of_Title_tl}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\LineCoffin{
    \textcolor{black}{\rule[-1.5pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\CoffinWidth\InitialCoffin\relax}{0.6pt}}
  }
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,t]\RestCoffin[l,b]
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,b]\InitialCoffin[r,b]
  \par\vspace*{5\baselineskip}\noindent\TypesetCoffin\LineCoffin (0mm, 0mm)\vspace{3\baselineskip}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\sottomomento}[1]{{\intestfont{#1}}\par\medskip}




\begin{document}







\sottomomento{Inno di Lode}
\gloria
\newpage%************************
\momento[0.05em]{Riti di introduzione}
\newpage%************************
\momento{Liturgia della parola}
\begin{lettura}[Prima]{Dagli Atti degli Apostoli}{At\,2,\,42--47}
\lettrine[lines=3]{E}{rano} perseveranti nell'insegnamento degli apostoli e nella comunione, nello spezzare il pane e nelle preghiere. Un senso di timore era in tutti, e prodigi e segni avvenivano per opera degli apostoli. Tutti i credenti stavano insieme e avevano ogni cosa in comune; vendevano le loro proprietà e sostanze e le dividevano con tutti, secondo il bisogno di ciascuno. Ogni giorno erano perseveranti insieme nel tempio e, spezzando il pane nelle case, prendevano cibo con letizia e semplicità di cuore, lodando Dio e godendo il favore di tutto il popolo. Intanto il Signore ogni giorno aggiungeva alla comunità quelli che erano salvati.
\end{lettura}
\newpage%************************
\begin{lettura}[Seconda]{Dalla prima lettera ai Corinzi}{1Cor\,13,\,1--13}
\lettrine[lines=3]{S}{e parlassi} le lingue degli uomini e degli angeli, ma non avessi la carità, sarei come bronzo che rimbomba o come cimbalo che strepita.
E se avessi il dono della profezia, se conoscessi tutti i misteri e avessi tutta la conoscenza, se possedessi tanta fede da trasportare le montagne, ma non avessi la carità, non sarei nulla.
E se anche dessi in cibo tutti i miei beni e consegnassi il mio corpo per averne vanto, ma non avessi la carità, a nulla mi servirebbe.
La carità è magnanima, benevola è la carità; non è invidiosa, non si vanta, non si gonfia d'orgoglio, non manca di rispetto, non cerca il proprio interesse, non si adira, non tiene conto del male ricevuto, non gode dell'ingiustizia ma si rallegra della verità. Tutto scusa, tutto crede, tutto spera, tutto sopporta.
La carità non avrà mai fine. Le profezie scompariranno, il dono delle lingue cesserà e la conoscenza svanirà. Infatti, in modo imperfetto noi conosciamo e in modo imperfetto profetizziamo. Ma quando verrà ciò che è perfetto, quello che è imperfetto scomparirà. Quand'ero bambino, parlavo da bambino, pensavo da bambino, ragionavo da bambino. Divenuto uomo, ho eliminato ciò che è da bambino.
Adesso noi vediamo in modo confuso, come in uno specchio; allora invece vedremo faccia a faccia. Adesso conosco in modo imperfetto, ma allora conoscerò perfettamente, come anch'io sono conosciuto. 
Ora dunque rimangono queste tre cose: la fede, la speranza e la carità. Ma la più grande di tutte è la carità!
\end{lettura}




\end{document}
```

The corresponding result is the following:

[image]
[image]

### MWE with `reledmac` and `reledpar`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

% reledpar and reledmac packages
% https://tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/reledmac/
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\numberlinefalse 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[paperwidth=120mm,paperheight=210mm,top=12mm,bottom=25mm,outer=20mm,inner=13mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{matrita}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\respfont}{\bfseries}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{respcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{etgray}{gray}{0.8}
\setlength{\afterpoemtitleskip}{2ex plus 0ex minus 1ex}
\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus 2ex}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
\setlength{\titleindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\definecolor{crosscolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\renewcommand{\intestfont}[1]{{\Large\scshape\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\nomelibrofont}[1]{{\bfseries#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCoffin\InitialCoffin
\NewCoffin\RestCoffin
\NewCoffin\LineCoffin
\newlength{\InitKernCorr}
\tl_new:N \Part_Title_tl
\tl_new:N \Rest_of_Title_tl
\tl_set:Nn \First_Title_tl {\tl_head:N \Part_Title_tl}
\tl_set:Nn \Rest_of_Title_tl {\tl_tail:N \Part_Title_tl}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\momento}{O{0em}m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \Part_Title_tl {#2}
  \setlength{\InitKernCorr}{#1}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\InitialCoffin{
    \normalfont\scalebox{2}{\Large\textcolor{red}{\First_Title_tl}\hspace{\InitKernCorr}}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\RestCoffin{
    \normalfont\Large\textcolor{red}{\MakeTextUppercase \Rest_of_Title_tl}
  }
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\LineCoffin{
    \textcolor{black}{\rule[-1.5pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\CoffinWidth\InitialCoffin\relax}{0.6pt}}
  }
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,t]\RestCoffin[l,b]
  \JoinCoffins\LineCoffin[l,b]\InitialCoffin[r,b]
  \par\vspace*{5\baselineskip}\noindent\TypesetCoffin\LineCoffin (0mm, 0mm)\vspace{3\baselineskip}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\sottomomento}[1]{{\intestfont{#1}}\par\medskip}




\begin{document}






\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
   \beginnumbering
   \pstart
\sottomomento{Inno di Lode}
\gloria
\newpage%************************
\momento[0.05em]{Riti di introduzione}
\newpage%************************
\momento{Liturgia della parola}
\begin{lettura}[Prima]{Dagli Atti degli Apostoli}{At\,2,\,42--47}
\lettrine[lines=3]{E}{rano} perseveranti nell'insegnamento degli apostoli e nella comunione, nello spezzare il pane e nelle preghiere. Un senso di timore era in tutti, e prodigi e segni avvenivano per opera degli apostoli. Tutti i credenti stavano insieme e avevano ogni cosa in comune; vendevano le loro proprietà e sostanze e le dividevano con tutti, secondo il bisogno di ciascuno. Ogni giorno erano perseveranti insieme nel tempio e, spezzando il pane nelle case, prendevano cibo con letizia e semplicità di cuore, lodando Dio e godendo il favore di tutto il popolo. Intanto il Signore ogni giorno aggiungeva alla comunità quelli che erano salvati.
\end{lettura}
\newpage%************************
\begin{lettura}[Seconda]{Dalla prima lettera ai Corinzi}{1Cor\,13,\,1--13}
\lettrine[lines=3]{S}{e parlassi} le lingue degli uomini e degli angeli, ma non avessi la carità, sarei come bronzo che rimbomba o come cimbalo che strepita.
E se avessi il dono della profezia, se conoscessi tutti i misteri e avessi tutta la conoscenza, se possedessi tanta fede da trasportare le montagne, ma non avessi la carità, non sarei nulla.
E se anche dessi in cibo tutti i miei beni e consegnassi il mio corpo per averne vanto, ma non avessi la carità, a nulla mi servirebbe.
La carità è magnanima, benevola è la carità; non è invidiosa, non si vanta, non si gonfia d'orgoglio, non manca di rispetto, non cerca il proprio interesse, non si adira, non tiene conto del male ricevuto, non gode dell'ingiustizia ma si rallegra della verità. Tutto scusa, tutto crede, tutto spera, tutto sopporta.
La carità non avrà mai fine. Le profezie scompariranno, il dono delle lingue cesserà e la conoscenza svanirà. Infatti, in modo imperfetto noi conosciamo e in modo imperfetto profetizziamo. Ma quando verrà ciò che è perfetto, quello che è imperfetto scomparirà. Quand'ero bambino, parlavo da bambino, pensavo da bambino, ragionavo da bambino. Divenuto uomo, ho eliminato ciò che è da bambino.
Adesso noi vediamo in modo confuso, come in uno specchio; allora invece vedremo faccia a faccia. Adesso conosco in modo imperfetto, ma allora conoscerò perfettamente, come anch'io sono conosciuto. 
Ora dunque rimangono queste tre cose: la fede, la speranza e la carità. Ma la più grande di tutte è la carità!
\end{lettura}
   \pend 
   \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
\sottomomento{Inno di Lode}
\gloria
\newpage%************************
\momento[0.05em]{Riti di introduzione}
\newpage%************************
\momento{Liturgia della parola}
\begin{lettura}[Prima]{Dagli Atti degli Apostoli}{At\,2,\,42--47}
\lettrine[lines=3]{E}{rano} perseveranti nell'insegnamento degli apostoli e nella comunione, nello spezzare il pane e nelle preghiere. Un senso di timore era in tutti, e prodigi e segni avvenivano per opera degli apostoli. Tutti i credenti stavano insieme e avevano ogni cosa in comune; vendevano le loro proprietà e sostanze e le dividevano con tutti, secondo il bisogno di ciascuno. Ogni giorno erano perseveranti insieme nel tempio e, spezzando il pane nelle case, prendevano cibo con letizia e semplicità di cuore, lodando Dio e godendo il favore di tutto il popolo. Intanto il Signore ogni giorno aggiungeva alla comunità quelli che erano salvati.
\end{lettura}
\newpage%************************
\begin{lettura}[Seconda]{Dalla prima lettera ai Corinzi}{1Cor\,13,\,1--13}
\lettrine[lines=3]{S}{e parlassi} le lingue degli uomini e degli angeli, ma non avessi la carità, sarei come bronzo che rimbomba o come cimbalo che strepita.
E se avessi il dono della profezia, se conoscessi tutti i misteri e avessi tutta la conoscenza, se possedessi tanta fede da trasportare le montagne, ma non avessi la carità, non sarei nulla.
E se anche dessi in cibo tutti i miei beni e consegnassi il mio corpo per averne vanto, ma non avessi la carità, a nulla mi servirebbe.
La carità è magnanima, benevola è la carità; non è invidiosa, non si vanta, non si gonfia d'orgoglio, non manca di rispetto, non cerca il proprio interesse, non si adira, non tiene conto del male ricevuto, non gode dell'ingiustizia ma si rallegra della verità. Tutto scusa, tutto crede, tutto spera, tutto sopporta.
La carità non avrà mai fine. Le profezie scompariranno, il dono delle lingue cesserà e la conoscenza svanirà. Infatti, in modo imperfetto noi conosciamo e in modo imperfetto profetizziamo. Ma quando verrà ciò che è perfetto, quello che è imperfetto scomparirà. Quand'ero bambino, parlavo da bambino, pensavo da bambino, ragionavo da bambino. Divenuto uomo, ho eliminato ciò che è da bambino.
Adesso noi vediamo in modo confuso, come in uno specchio; allora invece vedremo faccia a faccia. Adesso conosco in modo imperfetto, ma allora conoscerò perfettamente, come anch'io sono conosciuto. 
Ora dunque rimangono queste tre cose: la fede, la speranza e la carità. Ma la più grande di tutte è la carità!
\end{lettura}
   \pend
   \endnumbering 
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages




\end{document}
```

The corresponding result is the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Second Edit

It looks like that, not only `\newpage` does not work, but also `\par`, or, `\nobreak`, or `\bigskip`, which are included in the `\newcommand` called `\momento`, here

```
\momento[0.05em]{Riti di introduzione}
```

and here

```
\momento{Liturgia della parola}
```

The command `\momento` is contained inside `matrita.sty`, and it is defined in this way:

```
\newcommand{\momento}[1]{%
 {\par\vspace{\premomentoskip}%
 \noindent\LARGE\maiuscolettospaziato{#1}}%
 \par\nobreak\bigskip%
}
```

where `\premomentoskip` is defined as

```
\newlength{\premomentoskip}
 \setlength{\premomentoskip}{2.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 1ex}
```

and `\maiuscolettospaziato` is defined as

```
ifxetex
 \newcommand{\maiuscolettospaziato}[1]{%
  {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=6}\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}}
\else
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\newcommand{\maiuscolettospaziato}[1]{%
 \textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\textls[80]{#1}}}}
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and well-constructed question! However, I'd suggest that you add one more MWE that reproduces those two issues. A short document, created in vitro, displaying one page break (`\newpage`) and the linespacing problems. It's much easier to help if we can see (the relevant portion of) your code.

Comment: I can immediately see one red flag in your second code snippet, though: **never** leave empty lines between `\pstart` and `\pend`. In LaTeX, an empty line is read as a command to break the paragraph and start a new one. But with `reledmac`, you have to break text into paragraphs **explicitly**, with `\pstart` and `\pend`. Leaving empty lines is **known** to mess up things (f.i. the line spacing). (Empty lines outside of a `\pstart`-`\pend` group are fine.) (And if you are leaving "empty" lines to increase clarity and structure in your source, then "escape" them with a `%` sign.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @marquinho ...!! I trying to set up the code following your advices..! I am also trying to create a clearer MWE to post here :)

Comment: @marquinho: here you are a MWE, including code, results and explanations... :)

Comment: Nice! I've only time for a quick look, but I found the following: One of the spacing problems occurs at the lines "Gesù Cristo con ... Dio Padre". These lines are not from your input, rather they are the final lines of the custom command `\gloria`, defined in the file `matrita.sty`. If you [backup that file and then] change the lines `\\nella gloria di Dio Padre. \rispostatutti{Amen.}` to `\\
nella gloria di Dio Padre.\\ \rispostatutti{Amen.}` (i.e. **add** the line break `\\ `) then it solves the issue. You might want to try and see if this solves the other cases too!

Comment: [Should you find that this approach works, there are better ways to implement it, btw. It's not strictly necessary to actually *change* the file `matrita.sty`, as I proposed, when you can write a couple lines in *your* `.tex` that "patch" the command. And in the end you might want to contact the package author and suggest improvements.]

Comment: `\newpage` can't work directly in parallel typesetting with reledpar. You should use `\ledpb` and multiple run (see handbbok)

Comment: @marquinho, thanks a lot! However, I did not understand what you mean with "you can write a couple lines in your .tex that "patch" the command"... do you have an example in mind to show me?... Yes yes, I have contacted the author of ```Matrita```, and he gave me some general input about which packages I might use (no specific and technical details / examples)..

Comment: @Maïeul thanks a lot for your comment! I have read some relevant parts of the [handbook](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledpar.pdf), but I do not understand how to use ```\ledpb```. Do you have any MWE to show me, where ```\newpage``` is  replaced by ```\ledpb``` ? Also, I did not understand what you mean with "multiple run"....  :)

Comment: Well, i general, reledmac and reledpar need multiple runs of latex. You don't get the correct result at the fist run, but only at the second, third, fourth one... That is why the reledmac handbook explicitly say that you should use tool like `latemk` to be sur to get the correct number of latex run.

Comment: And for `ledpb`, there is no MWE to produce : just call it at the good place inside a `pstart` context, and in the similar place on the other page.

Comment: Thanks @Maïeul .....I tried many many times to compile my code (I guess as "to run" you mean "to compile") by using ```\ledpb```, just before the command ```\sottomomento```, i.e. ```\ledpb \sottomomento{Memoria del Battesimo}```, but the ```\sottomomento{Memoria del Battesimo}``` does not go to the following page... I do not know anymore what to do to correct the issue related to ```\newpage```.....

Comment: @Maïeul .... I have updated my question with a **Second Edit**, where I explain that not only ```\newpage``` does not work, but also ```\par```, or, ```\nobreak```, or ```\bigskip```, which are included in the ```\newcommand``` called ```\momento``` ......maybe you have a guess also for that ?!    :-)

Comment: Off-topic: I'm curious what the second language of the ceremony (and the Bible readings) will be? (Just a personal curiosity as a fellow polyglot :) ) And note: You are loading package `graphicx` twice, you can remove the second instance :)

Comment: @marquinho... sorry I forgot to reply to this comment.. :-) ...btw, the two languages will be Italian and Finnish.... even though I wanted to add English as well... but I think that, for three languages, the method of "facing pages", i.e. one language on left pages and a second language on right pages would be inadequate, and probably the method of "parallel columns" would be better...but that one is a different topic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can always be some conflict between packages that redefine  fundamentals (such as the shape and setup of paragraphs and the layout of pages) aggressively, and there's no guarantee that the respective expectations of the packages can be accommodated and the conflicts can be solved. Especially when the packages are designed with different methods and tools.

Here, we have two (three) such packages interacting. On the one hand, `reledmac` unpacks the conventional LaTeX paragraph, does its line referencing magic, and recomposes the paragraph; `reledpar` interferes similarly with the conventional order and construction of pages. On the other hand, `matrita` is build with a very specific kind of document in mind, and sets very peculiar requirements on LaTeX concerning page and paragraph structure.

I don't know where things go wrong in the interaction between those packages, but here are solutions, or at least practical workarounds, for your two issues.

### 1 . Line breaks and spacing

**The first thing** to take care of are **empty lines**. In your second code snippet, you have left some empty lines between `\pstart` and `\pend`:

```
\pstart

Text for Language ONE 

\pend
```

**Avoid this at all cost**.  In conventional LaTeX, an empty line is read as an instruction to *break the paragraph* and start a new one. But with `reledmac`, you **must** break text into paragraphs *explicitly*, using `\pend` and then `\pstart`. Leaving empty lines is known to mess up things (f.i. the line spacing).

Empty lines *between paragraphs* are fine. And if you need some "empty" lines in the code for better readability, you can always "escape" them with a `%` sign.

```
\pstart
Text for Language ONE 
\pend 

\pstart
%
Some more
%
text
%
\pend
```

**A second source** of spacing problems in your images is the behavior of the final lines in some blocks.

It seems that the special environments defined by `matrita` (such as `lettura`) conflict with the paragraph processing of `reledmac`. The following seems to solve it: **force a line break** at the end of your inputed text, right before `\end{lettura}`.

I'd use a `\\`, although this is, generally, not an advisable method to break lines in normal text ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines/82666#82666)). Here, we're inside an *environment* that makes generous use of `\\` to break lines (cf. `matrita.sty`) so we should be safe.

If, after the last line of your text you add `\\`, you get the correct line spacing.

```
Ma la più grande di tutte è la carità!\\   % I have added \\
\end{lettura}
```

[image]

You can apply this approach to solve all the other cases, I believe (and alternatively to `\\`, you can try `\newline`).

**There is one exception:** One case in your example is different, because the linespacing issue doesn't occur in your own input text.

The lines "Gesù Cristo con ... Dio Padre" are the final lines of the custom command `\gloria` defined in the file `matrita.sty`. *The solution is the same*, though: we need force a line break after the last text line and before the concluding command `\rispostatutti`. [I suppose this is a slip on the package creator's part – it may be worth it to tell them!]

This is the code from the file `matrita.sty`:

```
\\nella gloria di Dio Padre.
\rispostatutti{Amen.}
```

We'd like to have this instead:

```
\\nella gloria di Dio Padre.\\
\rispostatutti{Amen.}
```

To do so, we [**patch** the relevant command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch) involved in `\gloria` (actually called `\mtr@gloria`) with the tools provided by the excellent package `etoolbox`. (You won't need to load it, because `reledmac` calls it already.) We add the desired line break to the definition of the command, right after "Padre."

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mtr@gloria}{Padre.}{Padre.\\}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This solves the line spacing issue.

[image]

### 2 . Pagebreaks

I'm not familiar with the `xcoffin` constructions that you have adopted in your preamble to customize the `\momento` command. I have a hunch that the settings there *might* have something to do with the problems with page breaking, but as I said, I don't understand `Coffin`s well enough and I'd rather not touch that.

All the conventional solutions suggested do not work here; `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, `\pagebreak` from LaTeX do not have effect. Even the specific page breaking mechanism provided by `reledmac`, that is the command `\ledpb`  fails here (btw, this is **the way** to go if you need page breaks within a `numbering` block – forget about `\newpage` in those cases).

This approach, however, seems to work: Wherever you need a page break, *close the `pages` environment* (and the environments `Left` and `Right`) and typeset the `\Pages` at that point. Then, *start a new `pages` environment*.

So this:

```
erano salvati.\\
\end{lettura}
\newpage%************************
\begin{lettura}[Seconda]{Dalla prima lettera ai Corinzi}{1Cor\,13,\,1--13}
```

becomes this:

```
erano salvati.\\
\end{lettura}
   \pend
   \endnumbering 
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} 
  \beginnumbering
  \pstart
\begin{lettura}[Seconda]{Dalla prima lettera ai Corinzi}{1Cor\,13,\,1--13}
```

[image]

**Watch out!** You'll need to change the sequence of blocks in your code, jump around and copy-paste a lot, to preserve the correct left-right sequence. (For instance, you'll have to break down a long sequence `Left-Right-Pages` into shorter sequences `Left-Right-Pages-Left-Right-Pages-Left-Right-Pages`.) But it does work in all the cases you singled out in your example.

### 3 . The empty page

You noticed that when you use `reledpar`, page 1 of the document is suddenly empty. And, may I add, *rightly so*! This is a feature, not a bug.

For parallel typesetting (and printing!) you need corresponding texts to be on opposite, facing pages: Left and Right. The first Left page in the document is page 2. Page 1 would be the cover of the booklet, or some introductory material. I'd recommend that you keep things this way, which will also help later with printing.

However, if you wish to change this, here's a quick fix: At the start of your document, tell LaTeX that the first page is an even page (f.i. number 0 or 2), i.e. a Left page. The first page of your PDF will then contain the first units of text.

```
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\begin{pages}
```

Comment: Thanks a lotttt @marquinho !!!!!!! REALLY AMAZINGGG !!!  I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @limone Very glad that it helped! The solutions are nothing special or original, but I did want to write as clear and detailed an explanation as possible :) You can thank, as customary here, with an upvote and, if the answer solved your issues, by "accepting" it (clicking the green "checkmark" at the top left). Again: you're welcome!

Comment: Done! ....if I forgot to upvote something else, please let me know :-).  ...Again many many thanks!! I am changing all the features and I think I will post here the final outcome of your solution in case someone else wants to have a quick glance to the final result  :-)

Comment: @limone Thank you! Feel free to post your final outcome, f.i. as an addition to the question, but if you do so, please take care to *not* overwrite the original question(s) you asked – that would be confusing to future readers. "Onnea hääparille!" (says DeepL) :-)

Answer (score 0):

the final version of this work is now public on github:

https://github.com/2behappy/bilingual_wedding_mass_booklet

You can see the final result in this PDF:

https://github.com/2behappy/bilingual_wedding_mass_booklet/blob/main/Mass_Booklet_Bilingual.pdf